# How should I think about Scala's Product classes?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

The package "scala" has a number of classes named Product, Product1, Product2, and so on, up to Product22.

The descriptions of these classes are surely precise. For example:

```
Product4 is a cartesian product of 4 components
```

Precise, yes. Communicative? Not so much. I expect that this is the perfect wording for someone who already understands the sense of "cartesian product" being used here. For someone who doesn't, it sounds a bit circular. "Oh yes, well of course Product4 is the *mumble* product of 4 *mumble-mumbles*."

Please help me understand the correct functional-language viewpoint.  What is the sense of "cartesian product" being used here?  What do the Product classes' "projection" members indicate?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

["The set of all possible pairs of elements whose components are members of two sets."](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

["Specifically, the Cartesian product of two sets X (for example the points on an x-axis) and Y (for example the points on a y-axis), denoted X × Y, is the set of all possible ordered pairs whose first component is a member of X and whose second component is a member of Y (e.g. the whole of the x-y plane)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

Perhaps better understanding can be gained by knowing who derives from it:

*Direct Known Subclasses:*
`Tuple4`

Or by, knowing it "*extends Product*", know what other classes can make use of it, by virtue of extending `Product` itself. I won't quote that here, though, because it's rather long.

Anyway, if you have types `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`, then `Product4[A,B,C,D]` is a class whose instances are all possible elements of the cartesian product of `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Literally.

Except, of course, that `Product4` is a Trait, not a class. It just provides a few useful methods for classes that are cartesian products of four different sets.

Comment: please do talk about "Or by, knowing it "extends Product", know what other classes can make use of it, by virtue of extending Product itself. " even if it is long. People will appreciate it.

Comment: @user319058 Go [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.Product), click "known subclasses", have fun.

Comment: Isn't this answer leaving out two critical things; ordering, and allows two instances of the same type? Multiplication is associative, so the order of the multiple elements isn't significant. Yet the ordering of the elements in `Product` is making it not associative. And a set technically reduces elements which are equivalent. So, having `Int` twice beaks the notion of set. Are there a more accurate terms than "product" and "set" for this abstraction?

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium I think you meant commutative, not associative. Regardless, a cartesian product is [neither associative, nor commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Non-commutativity_and_non-associativity).

Comment: I did mean commutative. My bad. And you're right. Here's where it is asserted on Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 66):

Everyone else has gone for the maths so I'll go for the silly answer just in case! You have a simple car which has a gearbox, a steering wheel, an accelerator and a number of passengers. These can each vary: *which gear are you in, which way are you steering, is your foot "on the floor"* etc. The gearbox, steering, accelerator etc are therefore *variables* and each has its own *set* of possible values.

The cartesian product of each of these sets is basically *all possible states that your car can be in*. So a few possible values are:

```
(gear,    steer,    accel,     pssngers)
--------|---------|----------|---------
(1st,     left,     foot down, none)
(neutral, straight, off,       the kids)
```

the size of the cartesian product is of course the product (multiplication) of the possibilities of each set. hence if you car has 5 gears (+ reverse + neutral), steering is left/straight/right, accelerator is on/off and up to 4 passengers, then there are 7 x 3 x 2 x 4 or 168 possible states.

This last fact is the reason that the cartesian product (named after **Rene Descartes** by the way) has the multiplication symbol `x`

Comment: Personally I find the maths explanation a lot simpler!

Answer (score 8):

From [this thread](http://www.nabble.com/what-is-a-Product-trait--td16906255.html):

> From mathematics, a Cartesian Product of two sets A, B is denoted as `AxB` and its elements are `(a, b)`, where a in A and b in B.
>
> For three sets, the elements of the (Cartesian) product are `(a, b, c)` and so on...
>
> So, you have tuples of elements, and indeed you can see in the Scala library that all the tuples (like [`Tuple1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Tuple1.html)) inherit the respective product trait (like [`Product1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Product1.html)).
>
> **Think of product as the abstraction and the respective tuple a concrete representation**.

The projection allows to get the instance of the 'n' class referenced by the Product.

Answer (score 4):

A cartesian product is a product of sets. Given sets A and B, A x B ("A cross B") is the set of all tuples (x, y) such that x is in A and y is in B. A cartesian product may be analogously defined on types: given types A and B, A x B is the type of tuples (x, y) where x is of type A and y is of type B.

So Product4 is the type of tuples (w, x, y, z), where w, x, y, z are components.

Answer (score 2):

I think somebody might feel confused for `Product` just works like a member iterator, just like I did.

In fact, I think in 2019 everybody knows what a **Cartesian Product** is. But where is Cartesian Product in a Tuple ? I know if we have {a,b,c} and {1,2,3} we'll get {a,1},{a,2}...{c,3}. But when we come across Tuple2(a,1) we just have (a,1), how can one object Product?

So let's treat classes that implement `Product` as declarations. If class A(String, Int, Double) implentment Product3 , we treat the class as result of a **Cartesian Product** of (String, Int, Double), thus you know you can use `_1` `_2` `_3`method now.