# Scala - Iterate over an Iterator of type Product[K,V]

Tags: scala, iterator

I am a newbie to Scala and I am trying to understand collectives. I have a sample Scala code in which a method is defined as follows:

```
override def write(records: Iterator[Product2[K, V]]): Unit = {...}
```

From what I understand, this function is passed an argument **record** which is an Iterator of type Product2[K,V]. Now what I don't understand is this **Product2** a user defined class or is it a built in data structure. Moreover how do explore the key-value pair contents of Product2 and how do I iterate over them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are Product2 is a built-in class and you can easily check it if you're in modern IDE (just hover over it with ctrl pressed), or, by inspecting file header -- if there is no related imports, like `some.custom.package.Product2`, it's built-in.

What is Product2 and where it's defined? You can easily found out such things by utilizing Scala's [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/#package):

[image]

In case of build-in class you can treat it like tuple of 2 elements (in fact Tuple2 extends Product2, as you may see below), which has ._1 and ._2 accessor methods.

```
scala> val x: Product2[String, Int] = ("foo", 1)
// x: Product2[String,Int] = (foo,1)

scala> x._1
// res0: String = foo

scala> x._2
// res1: Int = 1
```

See [How should I think about Scala's Product classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301907/how-should-i-think-about-scalas-product-classes) for more.

Iteration is also hassle free, for example here is the `map` operation:

```
scala> val xs: Iterator[Product2[String, Int]] = List("foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2, "baz" -> 3).iterator
xs: Iterator[Product2[String,Int]] = non-empty iterator

scala> val keys = xs.map(kv => kv._1)
keys: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> val keys = xs.map(kv => kv._1).toList
keys: List[String] = List(foo, bar, baz)

scala> xs
res2: Iterator[Product2[String,Int]] = empty iterator
```

Keep in mind though, that once iterator was consumed, it transitions to empty state and can't be re-used again.

Answer (score 1):

[Product2](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Product2.scala#L1) is just two values of type K and V.

use it like this:

`write(List((1, "one"), (2, "two")))`

the prototype can also be written like: `override def write(records: Iterator[(K, V)]): Unit = {...}`

To access values `k` of type `K` and `v` of type `V`.

```
override def write(records: Iterator[(K, V)]): Unit = {
  records.map{case (k, v) => w(k, v)}
}
```