# Scala case class extending Product with Serializable

Tags: scala, types, traits, case-class

I am learning scala and tried following form Scala Cookbook:

```
trait Animal
trait FurryAnimal extends Animal
case class Dog(name:String) extends Animal
case class Cat(name:String) extends Animal
```

Now when I did following as :

```
val x = Array(Dog("Fido"),Cat("Felix"))
```

it show result as :

```
x:Array[Product with Serializable with Animal] = Array(Dog(Fido),Cat(Felix))
```

*Although I know that a case class is mixed in with Product trait*

What I am not getting is : `Product with Serializable with Animal`

***As per my understanding Product has something to do with Pattern matching***

I did google it but didn't get anything.Please Help to get me the concept in detail.

Thanks

Comment: Hey its a heterogeneous Array and both the Elements extends Animal, hence with Animal. If you put both these case classes inside another case class and then add that case class to the array. you would get the array of the case class.
 I was myself searching for a good read on this Product with Serializable back some time.. But didn't found one. Maybe someone may clear our thoughts.!

Comment: http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/06/04/more-on-sealed.html

Comment: also https://github.com/scala/scala-abide/issues/41

Comment: @som-snytt : Yes I saw that but my question is why compiler is doing so, Is there any specific reason .As far as  my understanding is that the signature is doing something with Pattern Matching(I may be wrong here),But I am not clear.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is an expected behavior because of how `case class` works. `case class` automatically `extends` two traits, namely `Product` and `Serializable`.

`Product` trait is extended as `case class` is an [algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) with [product type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type).

`Serializable` trait is extended so that `case class` can be treated as a pure data - i.e capable of being serialized.

Unlike `case class` `Dog` and `Cat`, your trait `Animal` does not extend `Product` or `Serializable`. Hence the type signature you see.

When you declare something like `Array(Dog(""), Cat(""))`, scalac needs to infer single [top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type) that can represent all the elements of given array.

That's why the inferred type is `Product with Serializable with Animal` as `Animal` did not extend `Product` nor `Serializable` while the `case class` did implicitly.

To work around this inference, you can either make type explicit by `Animal` or make `Animal` extend `Product` and `Serializable`.

```
trait Animal extends Product with Serializable

case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

Array(Dog(""), Cat("")) // Array[Animal] = Array(Dog(), Cat())
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the wiki links that made me clear with the mathematical model.

Answer (score 15):

All case classes in Scala posses a few properties:

1. They will automatically extend the `Product` trait and a default implementation will be provided for them, as they can be viewed as [a Cartesian Product of N records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301907/how-should-i-think-about-scalas-product-classes).
2. They will extend `Serializable` as they are serializable out of the box (as a design choice).
3. They will have an implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` provided by the compiler, which aids with pattern matching
4. They will provide `apply` and `unapply` methods, for composition and decomposition of the type.

Case classes are also Scala's way of expressing an [Algebraic Data Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), more specifically a [Product Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type). [Tuples are also a product type](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2), and as so they also extend the `Product` trait.

When you use two case classes with a common trait, the scala's compiler will use it's type inference algorithm to attempt to find the least upper bound (LUB) for the `T` type of the `Array`. Since both case classes extend `Product` and `Serializable` through the compiler, and the `trait` does not, it will during the search and apply it to the final calculated type.

If you want to avoid seeing that, you can have your trait explicitly extend those traits:

```
sealed trait Animal extends Product with Serializable
```

More on this topic can be found [here](https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/05/09/product-with-serializable.html)

Answer (score 0):

All case classes automatically extend `Product` and `Serializable`. It looks ugly ?  yes.
Basically ,`Product` can be viewed as heterogeneous collections. All Product classes viz. (Product1 , Product2 ...) extends `Product` which contains some common methods to use like `productArity` , `productElement` etc.

Like Case classes other types that extends `Product` are `List`,`Tuple` etc

From my scala worksheet,

```
  val product : Product = (10,"String",3)         //> product  : Product = (10,String,3)
  product.productArity                            //> res0: Int = 3
  product.productElement(0)                       //> res1: Any = 10
  product.productElement(1)                       //> res2: Any = String
  product.productElement(2)                       //> res3: Any = 3

case class ProductCase(age:Int,name:String,ISBN:Int)
  ProductCase(23,"som",5465473).productArity      //> res4: Int = 3
```

For details look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301907/how-should-i-think-about-scalas-product-classes).