# Implicit JsonWriter for trait not working

Tags: scala, implicit, spray-json

I have class as below

```
trait RiskCheckStatusCode {
  def code: String
  def isSuccess: Boolean
}

object RiskCheckStatusCode {

  val SUCCESS = SuccessRiskCheckStatusCode("1.1.1")
  val FAIL = FailRiskCheckStatusCode("2.2.2")

  case class SuccessRiskCheckStatusCode(code: String) extends RiskCheckStatusCode {
    override def isSuccess = true
  }

  object SuccessRiskCheckStatusCode {
    import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
    implicit val formatter = jsonFormat1(SuccessRiskCheckStatusCode.apply)
  }

  case class FailRiskCheckStatusCode(code: String) extends RiskCheckStatusCode {
    override def isSuccess = false
  }

  object FailRiskCheckStatusCode {
    import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
    implicit val formatter = jsonFormat1(FailRiskCheckStatusCode.apply)
  }
}
```

and now I would like to convert the list of RiskCheckStatusCode to json

```
object Main extends App{

import spray.json._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

  val l = List(RiskCheckStatusCode.SUCCESS, RiskCheckStatusCode.FAIL)

  implicit object RiskCheckStatusCodeJsonFormat extends JsonWriter[RiskCheckStatusCode] {
    override def write(obj: RiskCheckStatusCode): JsValue = obj match {
      case obj: SuccessRiskCheckStatusCode => obj.toJson
      case obj: FailRiskCheckStatusCode => obj.toJson
    }
  }

  def json[T](list: T)(implicit formatter: JsonWriter[T]) = {
    print(list.toJson)
  }

  json(l)
}
```

but the json method can not find jsonWriter[RiskCheckStatusCode]. 
Can you explain why? Maybe should I do it differently for trait type?

**Edit:**
It works for

```
 val l: RiskCheckStatusCode = RiskCheckStatusCode.SUCCESS
```

so the problem is with List[RiskCheckStatusCode] because I have a formatter for RiskCheckStatusCode, not for List[RiskCheckStatusCode]. I tried import DefaultJsonProtocol but it still does not work.

```
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._
```

I have to change the definitions? From

```
implicit object RiskCheckStatusCodeJsonFormat extends JsonWriter[RiskCheckStatusCode]
```

to

```
implicit object RiskCheckStatusCodeJsonFormat extends JsonWriter[List[RiskCheckStatusCode]]
```

error:

```
Error:(28, 7) Cannot find JsonWriter or JsonFormat type class for List[com.example.status.RiskCheckStatusCode]
  json(l)

Error:(28, 7) not enough arguments for method json: (implicit formatter: spray.json.JsonWriter[List[com.example.status.RiskCheckStatusCode]])Unit.
Unspecified value parameter formatter.
  json(l)
```

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine you are just not having `toJson` in your scope (it is located in the package object of `spray.json`).

Add it and your code should compile:

```
object Main extends App with DefaultJsonProtocol {

  import spray.json._

  // ...

}
```

Furthermore spray has some issues to lift `JsonWriter` through derived formats (see [this](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/issues/51) for details).

You can switch to `JsonFormat` instead:

```
implicit object RiskCheckStatusCodeJsonFormat extends JsonFormat[RiskCheckStatusCode] {
  override def write(obj: RiskCheckStatusCode): JsValue = obj match {
    case obj: SuccessRiskCheckStatusCode => obj.toJson
    case obj: FailRiskCheckStatusCode => obj.toJson
  }

  override def read(json: JsValue): RiskCheckStatusCode = ???
}
```

In addition, to cleanup the type of your `List` change the definition of `RiskCheckStatusCode` to ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36525804/scala-case-class-extending-product-with-serializable) explains more details):

```
sealed trait RiskCheckStatusCode extends Serializable with Product
```