# Why does the type result in "Product with Serializable with Animal" instead of just Animal?

Tags: scala, types

Suppose I have

```
val flag = true
```

why does the type result in `Product with Serializable with Animal` instead of just `Animal`?

```
class Animal(name : String)
case class Herbivore(name : String) extends Animal(name)
case class Carnivore(name : String) extends Animal(name)

val cow = new Herbivore("cow")
val tiger = new Carnivore("tiger")

if (flag) cow else tiger // Why is type Product with Serializable with Animal?
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the standard way to avoid these inferred types is to make the ADT root extend `Product with Serializable`—see e.g. [this article](https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/05/09/product-with-serializable.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Case classes [automatically extend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36526562/5205022) `Product with Serializable` so

```
class Animal(name : String)
case class Herbivore(name : String) extends Animal(name)
case class Carnivore(name : String) extends Animal(name)
```

is actually

```
class Animal(name : String)
case class Herbivore(name : String) extends Animal(name) with Product with Serializable
case class Carnivore(name : String) extends Animal(name) with Product with Serializable
```

Hence the most precise type of `if (flag) cow else tiger` expression compiler can infer is `Product with Serializable with Animal`. If we change from case classes to just classes like so

```
class Animal(name : String)
class Herbivore(name : String) extends Animal(name)
class Carnivore(name : String) extends Animal(name)
```

then the inferred type of the if-else expression would indeed be `Animal`.

As per @TravisBrown's suggestion, making ADT root extend `Product with Serializable` like so

```
abstract class Animal(name : String) extends Product with Serializable
case class Herbivore(name : String) extends Animal(name)
case class Carnivore(name : String) extends Animal(name)
```

would make the inferred type of the if-else expression also `Animal`.